# How do I prepend a string to the displayed/selected option from a <select> html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have the following HTML...

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I want to display the selected option with a prepended string that shows the quantity as follows "Qty: 1", "Qty: 2", "Qty: 3" based on the selected number from the dropdown.

Within the option dropdown I want to only display the numbers (i.e. without "Qty: " string prepended). An example of this style of qty dropdown is with Amazon.com products: [Amazon Product Example w. Qty Dropdown](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LYNW421). You should see the "Qty:" dropdown on the right side of the page.

This is what I am shooting for and it needs to work across desktop and mobile devices.

**I've already tried pseudo elements and adding spans as children to the select tags, to no avail.**

How can I implement this type of a dropdown?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the question? You're expected to take a crack at it and ask a specific question when you run into trouble.

Comment: Just concatenate the string `Qty:` and the value of the dropdown.

Comment: `'Qty:' + document.getElementById("dropdownid").value`

Comment: You can't do this automatically with HTML and CSS, you have to write a JavaScript event listener that concatenates the strings and adds it to the DOM.

Comment: @isherwood "How [do I] prepend a string to the displayed/selected option from a <select> html tag?"  "I've already tried pseudo elements and adding spans as children to the select tags, to no avail." I asked the question and explained what I had tried.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I will try this. Didn't know if there was an easier way to do this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You didn't _show_ what you tried, and that leaves your question very broad. That's the problem. We'll be happy to help with a little more direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  background: #e7e9ec;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
}

select,
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-indent: 5ch;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: #ADB1B8 #A2A6AC #8D9096;
  border-style: solid;
}

select:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #e77600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(228, 121, 17, .5);
}

span {
  top: 4px;
  left: 6px;
}

option[disabled] {
  background: #EEE;
  font-size: 1px;
}
```

```html
<label for="select">
<span>Qty: </span>
<select id="select">
  <option value="0">0 (Delete)</option>
  <option disabled></option>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option disabled ></option>
  <option>+10</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for reading my question. It appears it was clear enough to provide a basis for a very close solution to what I am going for, except the part that stated: "Within the option dropdown I want to only display the numbers (i.e. without "Qty: " string prepended)."  Also, to clarify, I want the "Quant: " string prepended the entire time on the select tag, not just after a selection is made. I linked an example to Amazon.com to show exactly what I am going for. If you look at the Qty dropdown there, it is exactly what I am trying to implement. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @mepley Regarding _"...It appears it was clear enough to provide a basis for a very close solution to what I am going..."_, I have to disagree. You are resorting to clarifications in comments, and chose not to show your code despite multiple requests. Just saying you've tried stuff is very different to showing what you have done.

Comment: @mepley
I updated the code and tried to simulate that drop down list displayed on amazon.com using native select. i hope this is helpful

Comment: @th31 Thank you very much for your help. I was able to use your approach to get this working just fine. Here is [my version](https://jsfiddle.net/d35xfoqz/) that used your code extensively. Thanks again. I will provide what I have already tried when posting future questions for better clarity. I now realize how important it is to do this.